# Why does this function argument become nonetype when I input an array

Tags: python, arrays, function

```
def printStats(description , array):
    print description
    array = array.sort()
    minValue = min(array)
    maxValue = max(array)

    return minValue, maxValue
```

I input an array into the second argument of the function but I get the error

```
 line 44, in printStats
    minValue = min(array)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

what does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Note that these are lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.sort()` sorts the list in place, and returns `None`, it doesn't return a sorted list.

```
array = array.sort()
```

Should just be:

```
array.sort()
```

(If you don't want to sort in-place, and instead want a new list, you could do `sorted(array)` - in this case, it makes sense to do it in-place, however).